How to revert to a prior app version when OS reports backed-up app is not compatible with device (while it is)?
From time to time, I take backups of all my apps using the Baria open-source app (although I see that Baria has not been updated since 2016).
I was using another app on my Official LineageOS 21, no Gapps, device.
I updated the app in question, and then it failed the Play Integrity check, which the app apparently just started checking for as of the latest version.
So, I uninstalled it, and looked up the last Baria backed-up version I had, and tried to install that.
However, I got the error message: "This app is not compatible with your device."
I also used the APK Explorer & Editor app to extract a backup of the same app from another similar device (the device is from the same manufacturer, series and year, but not the identical device).  I transferred it to the device in question and tried to install it, with the same result.
I am pretty sure the former version app is compatible.  So is there something in the Dalvik cache or something that the app developer left behind to prevent anyone from reverting to a previous version?
I wanted to wipe the Dalvik cache, but the LineageOS recovery does not have that option.  The only thing that one can do is a factory reset, and then it is an arduous task to reinstall & set up everything from scratch.
Or am I looking in the wrong place?
How can I install this prior version?

The age of Baria is most likely one problem. In 2016, all apps were solid APKs - one app = one APK. That has changed, nearly all apps installed via Play Store are now split APKs. As Baria is so old, if you encounter a split APK, this tool will most likely only back up the base APK, thus the backup will be incomplete.
The generic error message "This app is not compatible with your device." unfortunately doesn't help us much. The only way to get an error message we could work with is if you try to install the backup APK using adb install command. That requires a phone with enabled Developer menu and Android Debug Bridge (adb) plus a connected PC with Android SDK or minimal adb and drivers installed.
My guess for this error message is the new blocking of old apps Google has introduced with Android 14. If the app was already installed when you upgraded to 21, the app was not affected as the blocking only gets active if you try to install a new app.
This block can be bypassed via adb, see "App not installed as app isn't compatible with your phone" when installing APKs on Android 14

Thank you for your response.
I tried to install with adb install and it gave me: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SPLIT

I tried to install the bare apk with adb install and it gave me: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SPLIT
Should I try the override, or could that result in damage?
When I extract from another device using the APK Explorer & Editor app, as mentioned above, I get a folder with 3 files: base.apk, split_config.en.apk and split_config.xxhdpi.apk
Can adb install be used to install that?
When I tried it it gave an error message because the folder name does not end in .apk

@Johnson No overriding wouldn't get you a working app. The app is a split APK app, thus you need multiple APK files for installing. Normally there is base APK, one CPU architecture specific APK, one language specific APK and some apps also have separate settings APK and may be even more split APK files. Unless you have all of them (and install them together) the app will not work.
